# Batch process takes long time after reading 1 million records

Tags: spring-batch

I have a step that involves reading data from a complex join, using JdbcCursorItemReader. the first 1 million records took about 1 hour to run. 
After that the process slowed down that is has taken more than 15 hours to process 400 K records.

I have set the commit interval to 50000 records. 
Could this be a issue with the commit interval I have set or the database connection ?

Is it ok to use 50000 as commit interval ? A lot of posts mentioned going up to 10000 records.

Comment: As with any performance issue, have you done any profiling?  What have the numbers told you?  Can you share your profiling information here?

Comment: @MichaelMinella, Haven't done profiling yet. Let me set it up  and send you the information.